# Handle Paypal Payments/Checkout in a Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, paypal, payment

I want to implement payment/checkout, preferably the user stays on my website (Angular frontend).
I have been wandering around the docs of paypal for weeks, and googling too, but I don't seem to find an EFFECIENT way to do it (lack of drf tutorials and guides).
I also have seen django-payments, django-paypal, dj-paypal. but none of them has a clear docs about an integration with DRF...
I feel like I'm lost here.
any help? hints?

Answer (score 0):

There is an amazing payment gate that you can get help from. its name is [braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/), it's super amazing and it's used by big companies like Uber and Airbnb. it has a detailed document which helps you a lot.